# How to COUNTIFS only the filetered rows with multiple criteria in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet, worksheet

I have an excel worksheet where I have maintained the results of some students. I need to display the number of students **passed** or **failed** per **class**. I have obtained the same by using the `=COUNTIFS` function. But whenever I apply a filter, the values remain the same. `=COUNTIFS` function does not work with filtered rows.

```
=COUNTIFS(C2:C9,G4, D2:D9,"PASS")
```

[image]

How can I count only the filtered rows with multiple criteria?
(Same way like `=COUNTIFS` does, but only with the filtered rows.)

[Link to the Worksheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1noU-USIFm8QM4kcnGrbWwXCpX0ZUeEyh/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=109907677788022327633&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET($B$2:$B$9,ROW($B$2:$B$9)-MIN(ROW($B$2:$B$9)),,1)),($C$2:$C$9=G$4)*($D$2:$D$9=$F5))`  Using the information from the duplicate.

Comment: Why are you using OFFSET with B2:B9 while the ranges are C2:C9 and D2:D9?

Comment: You have to create an array of `1`s and `0`s that indicate whether the row is visible or not. `1` will be returned if the row is visible and `0` if it is not.  It does not matter the column as we only care if it is visible or not.  Then you multiply that against the other Boolean expressions.  If they all are true it returns `1` and if any are false then `0` and SUMPRODUCT adds up the results.  This is all explained in the duplicate.

Comment: Thanks, it works fine in Excel. But it gives error `SUMPRODUCT has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 1, column count: 1. Actual row count: 8, column count: 1.` in Google Sheets. Any fix for that?

Comment: this is why asking for either/or is not allowed on this site.  You need to choose one.  Your picture and most tags said Excel.  You are correct, this will not work in Google-sheets.  You will need to ask another question using ONLY the Google sheets tags to see if someone who is a subject matter expert for Google Sheets can help you find an alternative.

Comment: you can try: `=SUMPRODUCT(BYROW(D2:D9,LAMBDA(A,SUBTOTAL(3,A))),(C2:C9="III")*(D2:D9="pass"))`

Comment: Thanks @ScottCraner, it works in Google Sheets!

Comment: I just added that answer to the duplicate for future readers.